# Azure Queue trigger not working with Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-queues, azure-triggers

I have a spring boot application which will publish message on azure Queue. I have one more azure queueTrigger function written in Java which will listen to the same queue to which spring boot application has published a message. The queueTrigger function not able to detected messages published on queue.

Here is my publisher code

```
public static void addQueueMessage(String connectStr, String queueName, String message) {
    try {
            // Instantiate a QueueClient which will be
            // used to create and manipulate the queue
            QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClientBuilder()
                                        .connectionString(connectStr)
                                        .queueName(queueName)
                                        .buildClient();
    
            System.out.println("Adding message to the queue: " + message);
    
            // Add a message to the queue
            queueClient.sendMessage(message);
        }  catch (QueueStorageException e) {
            // Output the exception message and stack trace
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

Here is my queueTrigger function app code

```
@FunctionName("queueprocessor")
public void run(
   @QueueTrigger(name = "message",
                  queueName = "queuetest",
                  connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") String message,
    final ExecutionContext context
) {
    context.getLogger().info(message);
}
```

I'm passing same connection-String and queueName, still doesn't work. If i run function on my local machine then it gets triggered but with error  [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gxQk.png)

Answer (score 1):

As the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=java#encoding) suggests,

> Functions expect a base64 encoded string. Any adjustments to the encoding type (in order to prepare data as a base64 encoded string) need to be implemented in the calling service.

Update sender code to send base64 encoded message.

```java
String encodedMsg = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(message.getBytes())
queueClient.sendMessage(encodedMsg);
```

Comment: thanks its worked on local windows machine but when i deploy queueTrigger function to azure its not getting triggered

Comment: only reason it might not get triggered is the 'app settings' in Function app in Azure should have  storage connection string used in Function code. Also make sure you have queue there and no other app (like local debugger) is listening to same queue.

Comment: I checked, connection is good and no other listeners, still not working when i deploy but works fine on local machine

Comment: What do you see in App Isights log?

Comment: I'm not sure how Isights works as i'm new to azure platform

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring

Comment: typo in my previous reply. App Insights*